# ¿Cómo unir listas con unas condiciones dadas?

Tags: python, array, arraylist

espero esten bien, resulta que tengo la siguiente lista de datos:

```
list= [ '#Sta/Elev= 300',
 '0  2200.8     1.6 2199.63     2.2 2199.24     2.7 2198.82     3.2 2198.35',
 '3.7 2197.87     4.7 2196.77     5.3 2196.28     6.3 2195.59     6.8 2195.33',
 '7.3 2195.11     7.8 2194.87     8.2 2194.58     8.4  2194.5     8.9 2193.93',
 '10.3 2192.15    10.9  2191.4    11.1 2191.25    11.5 2190.89    12.7 
 '#Mann= 3 , 0 , 0',
 '#Sta/Elev= 190',
 '0  2193.2      .2 2193.09      .5 2192.89     1.2 2192.38     1.4 2192.23',
 '1.6 2192.16     2.1 2191.94     2.6 2191.61     3.4 2190.93     3.9 2190.47',
 '4.6 2189.91     5.1 2189.18     5.5 2188.77     5.8 2188.48     6.6 2187.79',
 '7 2187.31     7.6 2186.77     8.5 2186.12     8.7 2185.96     9.4 2185.44',
 '10.1 2184.83      11 2184.01    12.3 2182.62    13.9    2181    14.8 2180.12',
 '15.7 2179.25    15.9 2179.14    16.2 2178.82    16.9  2178.3    16.9 2178.25',
 '17 2178.22    17.3 2177.98    17.3 2177.97    17.7  2177.7      18 2177.41',
 '18.7 2176.76    20.9 2174.76    21.1 2174.58    23.6  2172.4    24.5  2171.7',
 '24.8 2171.45      252171.337    25.1 2171.28    25.2 2171.24    25.3 2171.19',
 '25.5 2171.12    25.9 2171.06    26.2 2171.03    26.9 2171.02    29.4  2171.1',
 '33.7 2171.14    33.9 2171.15    34.1 2171.16    34.2 2171.16    34.4 2171.19',
 '34.8 2171.24    34.8 2171.26    35.1 2171.33    35.4 2171.43    35.5 2171.44',
 '35.5 2171.45    36.3 2171.75    37.5  2172.2    37.6 2172.25    37.7 2172.29',
 '38.2 2172.47    38.3 2172.53    38.5  2172.6    38.7 2172.68    38.8 2172.74',
 '39 2172.82    39.4 2172.95    39.5 2172.99    39.7 2173.07   
 '#Mann= 3 , 0 , 0',]
```

Todos en formato string, mi deseo es hacer un array que contenga arrays especificando la list; es decir quiero un resultado final así:

```
list2=[[ '#Sta/Elev= 300',
 '0  2200.8     1.6 2199.63     2.2 2199.24     2.7 2198.82     3.2 2198.35',
 '3.7 2197.87     4.7 2196.77     5.3 2196.28     6.3 2195.59     6.8 2195.33',
 '7.3 2195.11     7.8 2194.87     8.2 2194.58     8.4  2194.5     8.9 2193.93',
 '10.3 2192.15    10.9  2191.4    11.1 2191.25    11.5 2190.89    12.7 2189.69',
 '13.5 2189.04      14 2188.58    14.8 2188.01    15.6 2187.45    15.6 2187.44',
 '15.7 2187.41      16 2187.17    16.1 2187.11    17.7 2186.14    19.2  2185.1',
 '19.6 2184.93    19.7  2184.9    19.7 2184.89    19.8 2184.88    20.1 2184.79',
 '20.2 2184.75    20.5 2184.66, #Mann= 3 , 0 , 0'],[repetir secuencia anterior]]
```

Esto he intentado pero me arroja error, agradezco su ayuda:

```
start_patt = ("#Sta/Elev=")
end_patt = ("#Mann")
for k in range(0,len(linelist)):
    r= start_patt in linelist[k]
    if r== True:
        print(yield linelist[k])
    s= end_patt in linelist[k]
    if s== True:
        print(linelist[k])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea que tienes es la correcta, buscar cada cadena de inicio y fin, lo que te faltaría es "recortar" la lista original:

```
nueva_lista = []
for i, elemento in enumerate(linelist):
  if '#Sta/Elev=' in elemento:
    start = i
  if '#Mann=' in elemento:
    end = i
    nueva_lista.append(linelist[start:end])
```

Esto funciona bien siempre que tengas los bloques de comienzo y fin. Podrías también, en este caso, dónde cuando finaliza un bloque inmediatamente sigue el siguiente depender solo del corte final:

```
nueva_lista = []
start = 0
for i, elemento in enumerate(linelist):
  if '#Mann=' in elemento:
    end = i
    nueva_lista.append(linelist[start:end])
    start = end + 1
```

De cualquier forma, lo que estamos haciendo es verificar en que elemento comienza y dónde finaliza cada bloque, esto lo podemos hacer gracias a `enumerate(linelist)`, que además de retornarnos cada línea nos da un numerador de cada una de estas. Con `start` y `end`, simplemente cuando completamos un bloque, hacemos un recorte o `slice` de la lista original, para agrupar las lineas del bloque: `linelist[start:end]` y por último agregamos esta nueva lista a `nueva_lista`, mediante: `nueva_lista.append(linelist[start:end])`

Por otro lado, según tu último comentario necesitarías las parejas de valores de la tabla de números que has capturado. Esto básicamente se logra, en primer lugar descartando las cadenas de inicio y fin y solo quedándonos con la tabla. Esta tabla, la recorremos por línea y separamos cada valor mediante `split()` y llevamos a `float`. Con `datos.extend()` vamos armando una lista larga de todos los elementos del bloque y por último con `list(zip(datos[0::2], datos[1::2]))` recortamos de a pares, para armar las parejas de datos.

```
nueva_lista = []
start = 0
for i, elemento in enumerate(lista):
  if '#Mann=' in elemento:
    end = i
    datos = []
    for fila in lista[start+1:end]:
      datos.extend([float(n) for n in fila.split()])

    nueva_lista.append(list(zip(datos[0::2], datos[1::2])))
    start = end + 1
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio me ha servido, mi pregunta es, ahora quiero hacer otro slice con esa nueva_lista finalmente quiero que me quede esa nueva_ lista así = [[[#staeleve],[numeros convertirlos a float],[[#staeleve],[numeros convertirlos a float]]],[]] y así muchas gracias de verdad por tu valioso aporte

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿los valores '#Sta/Elev=' y  '#Mann=' los necesitas para algo, o solo han sido los "detectores" de cada bloque?

Comment: Los necesito, en realidad son una pareja de coordenadas, mi deseo final es separar en listas coordenadas x, y de cada estación

Comment: Revisa mi última edicón

Comment: gracias Patricio

Comment: Aunque lo que quiero es que esa lista larga, en realidad este en pequeñas listas, me explico. la  estacion 1 tiene unas coordenadas x e y, esa sería una lista, otra lista sería la estación 2 con coordenas x e y y esas a su vez estan encerradas en una lista llamada estaciones, eso es básicamente lo que quiero, y perdon por no haber explicado un poco bien, aunque insisto, valoro mucho tu aporte

Comment: Si no te entendí mal, una cadena parcial como `0  2200.8` sería un pareja de valores x e y.  Es así? si es así , es lo que resuelve mi última edición, Revisa sino este ejemplo:  https://repl.it/@pmoracho/como-unir-listas-con-unas-condiciones-dadas